# In Flutter audio streaming is not working as expected via websocket and elevenlabs

Tags: flutter, websocket, just-audio

This is my code to continuously recieve stream of data from elevenlabs :

```
final socketChannel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(
    'wss://api.elevenlabs.io/v1/text-to-speech/$voiceId/stream-input?model_id=$model');
final AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();


final bosMessage = {
  "text": " ",
  "voice_settings": {"stability": 0.5, "similarity_boost": true},
  "xi_api_key":
      apiKey,
};

socketChannel.sink.add(jsonEncode(bosMessage));
socketChannel.stream.listen((message) async {

  final response = jsonDecode(message);
  if (response['audio'] != null) {
    try {
      final audioChunk = response['audio'] as String;
      final char  = response["normalizedAlignment"]["chars"];
      final uint8List = Uint8List.fromList(base64.decode(audioChunk));
      final streamController = StreamController<List<int>>();

      streamController.add(uint8List);

      await audioPlayer.setAudioSource(MyCustomSource(streamController.stream));
      try {
        await audioPlayer.play();
      } catch (e) {
        print('error ${e}');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error setting audio source and playing: $e");
    }
  }
});
```

And MyCustomSource for playing it :

```
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';

class MyCustomSource extends StreamAudioSource {
  final Stream<List<int>> byteStream;
  final List<int> bytes = [];
  MyCustomSource(this.byteStream) {
    byteStream.listen((data) {
      bytes.addAll(data);
    });
  }

  @override
  Future<StreamAudioResponse> request([int? start, int? end]) async {
    start ??= 0;
    end ??= bytes.length;
    return StreamAudioResponse(
      sourceLength: bytes.length,
      contentLength: end - start,
      offset: start,
      stream: Stream.value(bytes.sublist(start, end)),
      contentType: 'audio/mpeg',
    );
  }
}
```

The issue is that sometiimes it skips some words, sometime it abruptly stops and starts a new word and so on. It iisn't playing it smoothly from start to finish. How can I. fix this?